# Create multiple subsets in a loop

Tags: r

Using R, I am trying to find how many same elements are contained in the 1st and 2nd column, 1st and the 3rd, 1st and the 4th etc... As an output I would like to have a data frame in which is stated how many rows in the original data set met the condition.

The only idea I had was to use the `subset` function which works perfectly when the column is defined as `data$a` for example. But as I came to realize I can not use the subset function in a loop and I really have no idea what else I can use.

Any help is really appreciated.

```
D <- 0

a <-floor(runif(10, 1,101)) 
b <-floor(runif(10, 1,101))
c <-floor(runif(10, 1,101))
d <-floor(runif(10, 1,101))

data <- cbind(a,b,c,d) #Generate random data

for(i in 2:ncol(data)){
sub<- nrow(subset(data, a == 10 & data[,i] == 10)) #Compare a with all other columns and return the number of rows
D[,paste0("col_",i)] <- sub #output
}
```

Comment: For your random data, you could also use the one-liner `data <- matrix(sample(100L, 40, replace=TRUE)- 1L, 10)`. You should also use `set.seed` to make the result reproducible. Also, note that data is a matrix, so that `data$<whatever>` will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Te data I am actually working with is not random. I used random data for this question because it was easier for me to create the reproducible example like this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can do `colSums(data[data[,1]==10, -1, drop=FALSE]==10)`:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 500
x <- 5:20
data <- data.frame(a=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), b=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), c=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), d=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE))
data[data[,1]==10, -1, drop=FALSE] # or data[data$a==10, ...]
colSums(data[data[,1]==10, -1, drop=FALSE]==10) # or data[data$a==10, ...]
```

but you will have problems if there is no value `10` in `a`, e.g.:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 500
x <- 5:20
data <- data.frame(a=10L+sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), b=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), c=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), d=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE))
data[data[,1]==10, -1, drop=FALSE] # or data[data$a==10, ...]
colSums(data[data[,1]==10, -1, drop=FALSE]==10) # or data[data$a==10, ...]
```

You have to test this situation first by

```
any(data$a==10)
```

**Here is a solution using the recycling rule:**

```
data <- as.matrix(data)
colSums(data[,1]==10 & data[, -1]==10)
```

This solution has not the problem mentioned above.

**Here is a solution with `data.table`:**

```
library("data.table")

set.seed(42)
n <- 500
x <- 5:20
data <- data.table(a=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), b=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), c=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), d=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE))
data[a==10, sapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x==10)), .SDcols=-1]
set.seed(42)
data <- data.table(a=10L+sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), b=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), c=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE), d=sample(x, n, rep=TRUE))
data[a==10, sapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x==10)), .SDcols=-1]
```

Comment: The solution with the recycling rule worked perfectly for me. Thank you!